# How to show loading screen while loading json data or object & then start a new activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to to show loading screen while loading json data or object, and start a new activity with all the json object I loaded.

**My codes modal class**

```
    public catagory_data_modal(String catagorytitle, String poster) {
        this.catagorytitle = catagorytitle;
        this.poster = poster;
    }

    public void setCatagorytitle(String catagorytitle) {
        this.catagorytitle = catagorytitle;
    }

    public void setPoster(String poster) {
        this.poster = poster;
    }

    public String getCatagorytitle() {
        return catagorytitle;
    }

    public String getPoster() {
        return poster;
    }
}
```

**My Main activity class**

```
package com.sp2550.mstream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<catagory_data_modal> mmodaldata;
    RequestQueue mRequestque;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mmodaldata = new ArrayList<>();
        mRequestque = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        parsejson();

    }

    private void parsejson() {
        String url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/apppr49hyF0uoy8hV/Table%201?api_key=key3fE0";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("records");
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length();i++){
                                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONObject jsonObject  = object.getJSONObject("fields");

                                String poster = jsonObject.getString("background");
                                String companyname = jsonObject.getString("moviecompany");
                                mmodaldata.add(new catagory_data_modal(companyname,poster));

                            }

                        }

                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }

        });
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"data ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Dashboard.class).putExtra("data",mmodaldata);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        mRequestque.add(request);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please call the start activity function inside on response function.

```
ArrayList<catagory_data_modal> mmodaldata;
RequestQueue mRequestque;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mmodaldata = new ArrayList<>();
    mRequestque = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parsejson();

}

private void parsejson() {
    String url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/apppr49hyF0uoy8hV/Table%201?api_key=key3fE0";

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Dashboard.class).putExtra("data",mmodaldata);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    MainActivity.this.finish();
                        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("records");
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length();i++){
                            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONObject jsonObject  = object.getJSONObject("fields");

                            String poster = jsonObject.getString("background");
                            String companyname = jsonObject.getString("moviecompany");
                            mmodaldata.add(new catagory_data_modal(companyname,poster));

                        }

                    }

                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }

    });
    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"data ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    mRequestque.add(request);

}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you should start the activity _after_ you fill in the `mmodaldata` field. Otherwise what you start the activity with is always going to be empty.